# Return all elements of list containing certain strings

Tags: r, list

I have a list of vectors containing strings and I want R to give me another list with all vectors that contain certain strings. MWE:

```
list1 <- list("a", c("a", "b"), c("a", "b", "c"))
```

Now, I want a list that contains all vectors with "a" and "b" in it. Thus, the new list should contain two elements, `c("a", "b")` and `c("a", "b", "c")`.

As `list1[grep("a|b", list1)]` gives me a list of all vectors containing either "a" or "b", I expected `list1[grep("a&b", list1)]` to do what I want, but it did not (it returned a list of length 0).

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
test <- list("a", c("a", "b"), c("a", "b", "c"))
test[sapply(test, function(x) sum(c('a', 'b') %in% x) == 2)]
```

Comment: a variant: `function(x) all(c('a', 'b') %in% x)`

Answer (score 2):

Try `purrr::keep`

```
library(purrr)
keep(list1, ~ all(c("a", "b") %in% .))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Filter`

```
Filter(function(x) all(c('a', 'b') %in% x), test)
#[[1]]
#[1] "a" "b"

#[[2]]
#[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `grepl`:

```
> list1[grepl("a", list1) & grepl("b", list1)]
[[1]]
[1] "a" "b"

[[2]]
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```